# Recommended way for Postman collections to access APIs in Azure Virtual Network?

Tags: azure, postman, azure-virtual-network, web-api-testing

We are developing Postman collections for internally developed APIs which will eventually be deployed in Azure Virtual Networks.

Is there any recommended way for Postman to gain access to the vnet?

Answer (score 0):

For Postman collections to access APIs in Azure Virtual Network, you need to create an Azure API Management service instance by using the Azure portal and integrate your Postman with Azure API Management.

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/get-started-create-service-instance

https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/deploying-an-api/deploying-an-api-azure/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/export-api-postman

Once connected to Azure API Management, you can view your API deployment status and history from within Postman. You can also export your OpenAPI definition from Postman to Azure API Management, or import a definition from Azure to use it in Postman.

NOTE: Currently, you can only export HTTP APIs from API Management directly to Postman.

OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.0 definitions are supported. Some properties of the OpenAPI specification aren't supported by Azure API Management. For more information, refer below article on API import restrictions and known issues:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions